# vuejs : best way to call multiple actions from vuex

Tags: vue.js, vuex, store

I am working on a project in which I am using Vue js and electron. To manage the state I use vuex.
I have at least 15 actions to call in only one Vue file.

```js
methods: {
  ...mapActions('Store1', ['FETCH_AB']),
  ...mapActions('Store2', ['FETCH_DS']),
  ...mapActions('Store3', ['FETCH_SD']),
  ...mapActions('Store4', ['FETCH_XD']),
  ...mapActions('Store5', ['FETCH_SD']),
  ...mapActions('Store6', ['FETCH_AZ'])
}
```

I don't know if it's the best method, because in my created method, I have:

```js
async mounted(){
  this.FETCH_AZ()
  this.FETCH_DS()
  ....
}
```

is this a good method for my program to work properly?

Comment: You can wrap those actions into another action and map only this action in your vue file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new special action which will `dispatch` all the others:

```js
actions: {
  FETCH_AB: ()  => {
    // ...
  },
  FETCH_DS: ()  => {
    // ...
  },
  FETCH_SD: ()  => {
    // ...
  },
  // Rest of the actions...


  FETCH_ALL: ({ dispatch }) => {
    // Dispatch all the actions here
    dispatch('FETCH_AB');
    dispatch('FETCH_DS');
    dispatch('FETCH_SD');
    //...
  }
}
```

Comment: you don't use async methodes ?

Comment: @kevinG73, It doesn't matter, you can also use `async`: `FETCH_AB: async ()  => { ... }`

Comment: but why dispatch and not commit ? i wonder what's happen when i'll use it my my application

Comment: The Vuex way to call an action is with `dispatch`, `commit` is to call a mutation. see the [docs](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/actions.html).